# Contact Search Column & Data Mismatch

Tags: wordpress, issues, search-results

We're running Civi 4.7.20 on Wordpress 4.8.  When searching for contacts, it appears that the column headers do not match with the data type for the fields.  However, when looking at an individual record, values appear in the proper fields.

This behavior was also observed in the demo sandbox.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10556 and is included in 4.7.21 version.

You can apply the PR on your site if you don't wish to upgrade now.